# mysql not starting in xampp even after changing mysql port and restarting the server

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have changed port number and restarted the service but still I am not able to start MySQL in `Xampp`.

Content of **my.ini** file:

[image]

and **config.inc.php**:

[image]

Comment: Why does it not start? What do the logs have for an error? Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: port 3306 is in use by C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL"!